# Read multiple columns in perl using while loop

Tags: perl, shell

I am stuck in a problem in Perl.

I want to read multiple columns in 1 line using while loop.

I know I can achieve this using shell script like below

```
cat file.txt|while read field1 field2 field3 field4
do
statement1
statement2
done
```

The same thing I want in Perl but don't understand how to get this.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Sumana

Comment: What do you want to split the line from the file on?

Comment: Yes, there might be many fields in file but I want to extract only n number of fields like shown above and then I will use these variables below. 

I know array is alternative but I wanted to check if there is any easier method available like shell provides here.

Comment: @Sumana, that doesn't extract n fields. What happens is all fields after the 4th get slurped into your "field4" variable. Maruice's answer behaves exactly the same. To discard the remaining, you need an additional `_` in bash or `undef` in the perl version.

Comment: @jordanm - good point.  I was working off the assumption of three fields.  Feel free to edit the script to reflect this reality if you want, or I can later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a loop, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $file = "MYFILE";
open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
my @lines;
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($field1, $field2, $field3) = split;
}
close $fh or die "Cannot close $file: $!";
```

In the loop, Perl will assign $_ the next line of the file, and with no args, split will split that variable on white space.

Comment: Yes. It solved my purpose. Thank you very much Maurice for your kind help.

Comment: My pleasure! Best of luck, and when you have a chance, if you haven't already, please mark my answer as accepted.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

use

```
perl -F -ane '....' your file
```

-F flag will store each field in an array @F.so u can use $F[0] for the first field.
for example:

```
perl -F -ane 'print $F[0]' your file
```

will print the first field of every line

if you are concerned about performance:

```
perl -lne "my($f,$s,$t)=split;print 'first='.$f.' second='.$s.' third='.$t" your_file
```

for a big example :also check [this](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-perls-f-flag.html)

Comment: I know array can solve this purpose but that's a bit lengthy and it uses memory also to assign many unwanted values so I wanted to check if Perl also provide any easier method like shell as in my example.